# Summing columns with hundred of lines from different files with python

Tags: python, file, numpy

I have dozens files (a, b, c, ...) each one with following format:

File a ------File b ------ File c -------    and so on 
x1a y1a | x1b y1b | x1c y1c | ... 
 
x2a y2a | x2b y2b | x2c y2c | ... 
x3a y3a | x3b y3b | x3c y3c | ... 
. 
. 
.

By keeping in mind that there are hundreds of rows with two columns in each file.
I want just to sum the second columns of each file row by row, i.e.,

Y1 = y1a + y1b + y1c + ... 
Y2 = y2a + y2b + y2c + ... 
Y3 = y3a + y3b + y3c + ... 
. 
. 
.

Then, creating a new two column file with content of:

x1a Y1 
x2a Y2 
x3a Y3 
. 
. 
.

Could some one help with that? 
Thank you!

Comment: So you don't care about `x1b`, etc.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I suggest you break this into smaller pieces. First you need to open a file and read the input from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very possible using `loadtxt` and some clever slicing.

From your example, it seems you want the first column from `file_a`, and the second column to be the summation of all `y` rows.  Here are the sample files I used:

```
file_a.txt      file_b.txt         file_c.txt
1 2             4 3                1 2
3 4             2 1                6 7
5 6             6 7                9 1
7 8             5 2                2 3
```

First, let's read the files into an array, by stacking then horizontally:

```
filenames = [f'file_{i}.txt' for i in ('a', 'b', 'c')]
arr = np.column_stack([np.loadtxt(f) for f in filenames])
```

```
[[1. 2. 4. 3. 1. 2.]
 [3. 4. 2. 1. 6. 7.]
 [5. 6. 6. 7. 9. 1.]
 [7. 8. 5. 2. 2. 3.]]
```

Now our indexing.  We can access all of the `y` columns by getting every other column, starting at index `1`:

```
arr[:, 1::2]
```

```
array([[2., 3., 2.],
       [4., 1., 7.],
       [6., 7., 1.],
       [8., 2., 3.]])
```

So now we can sum this array along the first axis, and use `column_stack` again to combine it with the first `x` column, and finally write to a file:

```
out = np.column_stack([arr[:, 0], arr[:, 1::2].sum(1)])
np.savetxt('out.txt', out, fmt='%d')
```

And here is `out.txt`:

```
1 7
3 12
5 14
7 13
```

Comment: Great, @user3483203! It solved my problem. I took advantage to learn about the loadtxt and conlumn_stack, which I didn't know. Thank you!